# How to match column/view width when using ListViews on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I have a collection of models that need to be displayed vertically.
Each models has 4 values like strings, that all have a fixed width except the first values.

Can't figure out how to make the first views/columns wrap_content and equal in width compared to each other.

I tried a TableLayout, but that does not keep the widths in different columns for the rows.

I tried to use a MvxLinearLayout with a custom adapter that picks the largest width and sets all other matching views/columns..

Both solutions didn't work, and ended up with to much hacking.

Anyone idea's how to display Android vertical collections with equal/matching column widths?

edit: Collection I'm using has structure like

```
List<Person>
where Person has { string Name, int Age, string Gender }
```

The Collection View I'm looking for: 
(where all first views in row must be all same size)

[image: example]

Comment: Have you considered using a GridView?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yes I did, but that would possibly end up with the same issue: equel\match width of first item of each row

Comment: Then you haven't tried GridView.

Comment: @Cheesebaron would you suggest to make an item of each field from person, or do you think its doable with keeping the person objects in tact? I will try again, but I think I will just end up with a gridview with 1 collumn where its hard to keep the same width for the first child views within the row